# Using the active userform as a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several userforms that I'm treating as it's own application. What I have right now is the following code that runs when you click the back button on most userforms and checks the user's windows credentials.

```
Sub backbutton()
If getWinUser = "Joseph.B" Then
MainMenu.Show vbModeless
ElseIf getWinUser = "Aaron.G" Then
MainMenu.Show vbModeless
ElseIf getWinUser = "Debralee.B" Then
MainMenu.Show vbModeless
ElseIf getWinUser = "Amanda.S" Then
MainMenu.Show vbModeless
ElseIf getWinUser = "Miguel.A" Then
MainMenu.Show vbModeless
Else: OLMenu.Show vbModeless
End If
End Sub
```

What I need to do now though is add the following code that helps remember the last window position of the active userform. I want to work this into the above code so it's one single sub to call.

```
PhoneHiring_Left = Me.Left
PhoneHiring_Top = Me.Top
BackStatus = True
Load frmPhoneHiring_Main
frmPhoneHiring_Main.Left = PhoneHiring_Left
frmPhoneHiring_Main.Top = PhoneHiring_Top
frmPhoneHiring_Main.Show vbModeless
```

Instead of putting this on each individual userform I'd like to add it to first sub with a variable that can be used to reference whatever the currently active form is. My initial thought is something like this:

```
PhoneHiring_Left = ActiveForm.Left
PhoneHiring_Top = ActiveForm.Top
BackStatus = True
Load frmPhoneHiring_Main
frmPhoneHiring_Main.Left = PhoneHiring_Left
frmPhoneHiring_Main.Top = PhoneHiring_Top
Unload ActiveForm
```

But it doesn't seem to work. ActiveForm doesn't seem to be an acceptable variable.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - you use the term "forms" so often, it's not clear which forms are meant in what context. It's also not clear what `Unload.Me` refers to. You have it all straight in your mind, but it's not coming across in your problem description... Can you maybe edit in some pseudo code that illustrates what you have in mind? Or a flow diagram?

Comment: Edited for clarity